# How to return a transposed matrix in a different class?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have my main class which asks to transpose my pre-existing matrix. I got the idea, but I can't return Matrix object. Gives an error of `Type Mismatch - cannot convert from int[][] to matrix`.

```
    public class Matrix {
    int numRows;
    int numColumns;
    int data[][];

    public Matrix transpose() {
    int[][] M = new int [numColumns][numRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            M[j][i] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return M;
}
```

Comment: change return type from `Matrix` to `int[][]`. `public int[][] transpose()`

Comment: @Goion I am not allowed to modify "public Matrix transpose() {"

Comment: Then create a new object of Matrix and return the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

**Option 1 (Change Return Type):**

Options 1 is to change return type from `Matrix` to `int[][]`.

```
public int[][] transpose() {
    int[][] M = new int[numColumns][numRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            M[j][i] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return M;
}
```

**Option 2 (Create an object and return it):**

Your Option 2 is to create an object and add transposed matrix to that object and return it.

```
public Matrix transpose() {
    int[][] M = new int[numColumns][numRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            M[j][i] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    return new Matrix(numColumns, numRows, M);
}
```

Assuming your constructor looks like this

```
public Matrix(int numRows, int numColumns, int[][] data) {
    this.numRows = numRows;
    this.numColumns = numColumns;
    this.data = data;
}
```